# Reducing match indentation for deeply nested properties

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, algebraic-data-types

I need to refer to a value deep within a structure which includes an `Option` nested in a `struct` property, nested in a `Result`.

My current (working) solution is:

```
    let raw = &packet[16..];
    match PacketHeaders::from_ip_slice(raw) {
        Err(_value) => {
            /* ignore */
        },
        Ok(value) => {
            match value.ip {
                Some(Version4(header)) => {
                    let key = format!("{}.{}.{}.{},{}.{}.{}.{}", 
                        header.source[0], header.source[1], header.source[2], header.source[3],
                        header.destination[0], header.destination[1], header.destination[2], header.destination[3],
                    );

                    let Count {packets, bytes} = counts.entry(key).or_insert(Count {packets: 0, bytes: 0});
                    *packets += 1;
                    *bytes += packet.len();

                    if p > 1000 { /* exit after 1000 packets */
                        for (key, value) in counts {
                            println!("{},{},{}", key, value.packets, value.bytes);
                        }
                        return ();
                    }
                    p += 1;
                }
                _ => {
                    /* ignore */
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

(The problem with my current code is the excessive nesting and the two matches.)

All I want is `PacketHeaders::from_ip_slice(ip) >> Ok >> ip >> Some >> Version4`.

How can I get this, or ignore a failure nicely (NOT crash/exit) for each captured packet?

Comment: have you tried `map` method?  You can also use if let for matching one case.
https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map

Comment: It would be nice to have a [mcve]; it's a bit hard to guess what are the types involved here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pattern matching nests, and the pattern for struct looks like struct literals with the addition that `..` means "and match all the rest, which I don't care about", similar to how the `_` pattern means "match anything". Meaning you can do

```
match PacketHeaders::from_ip_slice(raw) {
    Ok(PacketHeaders { ip: Version4(header), .. }) => {
        /* handle */
    }
    _ => {
        /* ignore `Err(_)` and other `Ok(_)` */
    },
}
```

and if you're going to ignore all but one case, you can use `if let`:

```rust
if let Ok(PacketHeaders { ip: Version4(header), .. }) = PacketHeaders::from_ip_slice(raw) {
    /* handle */
}
```

Comment: The OP is already using nested pattern matches, you may want to explain that pattern matching on _fields_ also nests.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes, it's the transition from `Ok(value)` to `match value.ip` that's got me confused.  I don't see how that's handled in this answer.

Comment: @mcarton We're nearly there, with `if let Ok(PacketHeaders { ip: Some(Version4(header)) }) = PacketHeaders::from_ip_slice(raw) {` I get "
error[E0027]: pattern does not mention fields `link`, `vlan`, `transport`, `payload`
  --> src/main.rs:55:13".

Comment: Got there with: `if let Ok(PacketHeaders { ip: Some(Version4(header)), link: _, vlan: _, transport: _, payload: _}) = PacketHeaders::from_ip_slice(raw) {`.

Answer (score 0):

Code ended up being:

```
    let raw = &packet[16..];
    if let Ok(PacketHeaders { ip: Some(Version4(header)), link: _, vlan: _, transport: _, payload: _}) = PacketHeaders::from_ip_slice(raw) {
        let key = format!("{}.{}.{}.{},{}.{}.{}.{}", 
            header.source[0], header.source[1], header.source[2], header.source[3],
            header.destination[0], header.destination[1], header.destination[2], header.destination[3],
        );

        let Count {packets, bytes} = counts.entry(key).or_insert(Count {packets: 0, bytes: 0});
        *packets += 1;
        *bytes += packet.len();
    }
```

Comment: You can use `..` to ignore all the rest. I've edited my answer to reflect that. If your OP had a MVE, it could have provided this answer from the beginning.

Comment: @mcarton Thanks for your help. Sorry for not providing a MVE, I do not yet know enough to be able to construct a synthetic structure of the same shape as the `Result(PacketHeaders)`.